# ImageDataGenerator flow_from_dataframe multi_output regression and classification syntax problem

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

**The Context**

I am using the tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image ImageDataGenerator

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
```

I've struggled to find an example of a "multi_output" custom generator that passes a vector of floats (e.g. 4 vector representing a bounding box) as the label to one of the 2 network heads, and a one-hot encoded vector (e.g. 3 classes) as the label to the other head.

The first network head will perform regression on the 4-vector bounding box

[First Head](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCRZQ.png)

and the second network head will perform classification on the "one-hot" 3-vector.

[Second Head](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcHjU.png)

I have a structure that is very similar to the one found [here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2020/10/12/multi-class-object-detection-and-bounding-box-regression-with-keras-tensorflow-and-deep-learning/).

The only difference is that I dont want to load all the images into memory at once, hence my desire to use a generator.

I think my code is close, but the variety of examples I've found are not quite what I need.

This is what I first had (see **Additional Details** below for what i currently have):

```
def generate_image_generator(generator, data_directory, data_items, target_size, classes, batch_size, shuffle, class_mode):
frames=[]
for di in data_items:
    df = pd.read_csv(data_directory+di["file"])
    #df["cls"] = df["cls"].apply(lambda x: x.split(","))
    frames.append(df)
df = pd.concat(frames)
a = pd.get_dummies(df['cls'], prefix='cls')
df = pd.concat([df, pd.get_dummies(df['cls'], prefix='cls')], axis=1)
df.head()
#                                              y_col=(['sxu', 'syu', 'exu', 'eyu'], 'cls'),
genImages = generator.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=df, directory=data_directory, target_size=target_size,
                                          x_col="file",
                                          y_col=[('sxu', 'syu', 'exu', 'eyu'), ('cls_airplane', 'cls_face', 'cls_motorcycle')],
                                          class_mode="multi_output",
                                          classes=classes, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=shuffle, seed=2)
```

Notice in particular the following two lines:

```
 y_col=[('sxu', 'syu', 'exu', 'eyu'), ('cls_airplane', 'cls_face', 'cls_motorcycle')],
 class_mode="multi_output",
```

The first line is supposed to specify a list with 2 label elements (one for each of the  2 heads in my model, the 4-vector regression head, and the 3 vector classification head)

A sample from the CSV file that is loaded into the pandas dataframe is seen below

```
    id,file,sx,sy,ex,ey,cls,sxu,syu,exu,eyu,w,h
0,motorcycle.0001.jpg,31,19,233,141,motorcycle,0.1183206106870229,0.11801242236024845,0.8893129770992366,0.8757763975155279,262,161
1,motorcycle.0002.jpg,32,15,232,142,motorcycle,0.12167300380228137,0.09259259259259259,0.8821292775665399,0.8765432098765432,263,162
```

Notice that in the code above, I add additional "one-hot" columns (cls_motorcycle, cls_face, cls_airplane) to the pandas dataframe. These are the columns referenced in the second tuple that is in my "y_col" array.

[The augmented pandas dataframe that includes my one-hot columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXUL5.png)

**The Error**

I am using tensorflow's keras implementation. The error I receive is a "key error" into the pandas dataframe.

[Full Stack Trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGBdf.png)

Clearly tensorflow keras doesnt like the list of tuples I pass for the "multi_output" labels. It thinks the first tuple in the list is actually a single key into one column rather than 4 keys into 4 columns.

**The Question**

How can I configure [flow_from_dataframe](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator#flow_from_dataframe) with a "multi_output" regression label for one head, and a classification label for the second head?

**Additional Details**

I have now tried to do the following (notice I now yield a 2-tuple for the label - this is the latest state of my effort), and I think I got further.. However I dont think this is right yet (stack trace below code snippet):

```
def generate_image_generator(generator, data_directory, data_items, target_size, classes, batch_size, shuffle, class_mode):
frames=[]
for di in data_items:
    df = pd.read_csv(data_directory+di["file"])
    frames.append(df)
df = pd.concat(frames)

labels = ['sxu', 'syu', 'exu', 'eyu', 'cls_onehot']
df['cls_onehot'] = df['cls'].str.get_dummies().values.tolist()

genImages = generator.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=df, directory=data_directory, target_size=target_size,
                                          x_col="file",
                                          y_col=labels,
                                          class_mode="multi_output",
                                          classes=classes, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=shuffle, seed=2)

while True:
    images, labels = genImages.next()
    yield images[0], ([labels[0], labels[1], labels[2], labels[3]], labels[4])
```

I get further, so perhaps my generator is ok now, but I do see the following trace now (when I start to train the model):

[New Stack Trace During First Training Epoch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtwEr.png)

In the following pycharm debug view you can see the images and labels as they exist at the point that the generator "yields". Note, my batch size is 5.

[Batch of Images and Labels yielded by generator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtZqr.png)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the right answer:

```
def generate_image_generator(generator, data_directory, data_items, target_size, classes, batch_size, shuffle, class_mode):
frames=[]
for di in data_items:
    df = pd.read_csv(data_directory+di["file"])
    frames.append(df)
df = pd.concat(frames)

df['cls_onehot'] = df['cls'].str.get_dummies().values.tolist()
df['bbox'] = df[['sxu', 'syu', 'exu', 'eyu']].values.tolist()

genImages = generator.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=df, directory=data_directory, target_size=target_size,
                                          x_col="file",
                                          y_col=['bbox', 'cls_onehot'],
                                          class_mode="multi_output",
                                          classes=classes, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=shuffle, seed=2)

while True:
    images, labels = genImages.next()
    targets = {
        'class_label': labels[1],
        'bounding_box': labels[0]
    }
    yield images, targets
```