# How can I isolate why my tensorflow model has such a high loss and low accuracy?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

**The Context:**
I am creating a test application that largely replicates the functionality described [here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2020/10/12/multi-class-object-detection-and-bounding-box-regression-with-keras-tensorflow-and-deep-learning/).

I was able to run the code found in the tutorial linked above, and I see losses and accuracies that are reasonable, even after just a couple of epochs.

[Tutorial Code: Early into the training of the two-headed CNN, losses and accuracy look good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEIfW.png)

This is because the code starts with the VGG16 model and the already trained weights, and it freezes those layers so that no learning is required for the core classification.

My test code largely replicates the tutorial structure. It uses the exact same dataset, and the already-trained VGG16 weights. However I load the image dataset using generators (rather than pulling all data into memory, as the tutorial does).

You can find how I created those generators in the answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66424141/imagedatagenerator-flow-from-dataframe-multi-output-regression-and-classificatio/66427330#66427330). I had struggled for a while, before I finally got it to a point that I think is correct.

**The Problem:**
When I train my model the classification loss and accuracy are as expected, however the bounding box loss grows, and the bounding box accuracy does not improve, over the epochs.

[My Code: Even after just a couple epochs you see the bounding box loss starting to grow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5P0ps.png)

**Further Details:**
I've spent a lot of time looking at the (image, target) tuples yielded by the generator, and I think I am handling the yielded data properly (including the unitrect).

[A pycharm view of the images and target tuples yielded by generator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rXFEI.png)

In fact I've also added a debug mode that allows me to display the images and rectangles fed into the training session.
[A motorcycle with the bounding box as computed from the unit rectangle bounding box loaded from CSV into the dataframe (df); df is an input to flow_from_dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1y18a.png)

The model I am using:

```
imodel = tf.keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16(weights=None, include_top=False,
                                           input_tensor=Input(shape=(224, 224, 3)))
imodel.load_weights(weights, by_name=True)
imodel.trainable = False
# flatten the max-pooling output of VGG
flatten = imodel.output
flatten = Flatten()(flatten)
# construct a fully-connected layer header to output the predicted
# bounding box coordinates
bboxHead = Dense(128, activation="relu")(flatten)
bboxHead = Dense(64, activation="relu")(bboxHead)
bboxHead = Dense(32, activation="relu")(bboxHead)
bboxHead = Dense(4, activation="sigmoid",
                 name="bounding_box")(bboxHead)
# construct a second fully-connected layer head, this one to predict
# the class label
softmaxHead = Dense(512, activation="relu")(flatten)
softmaxHead = Dropout(0.5)(softmaxHead)
softmaxHead = Dense(512, activation="relu")(softmaxHead)
softmaxHead = Dropout(0.5)(softmaxHead)
softmaxHead = Dense(len(classes), activation="softmax",
                    name="class_label")(softmaxHead)
# put together our model which accept an input image and then output
# bounding box coordinates and a class label
model = Model(
    inputs=imodel.input,
    outputs=(bboxHead, softmaxHead))
# define a dictionary to set the loss methods -- categorical
# cross-entropy for the class label head and mean absolute error
# for the bounding box head
losses = {
    "class_label": "categorical_crossentropy",
    "bounding_box": "mean_squared_error",
}
# define a dictionary that specifies the weights per loss (both the
# class label and bounding box outputs will receive equal weight)
lossWeights = {
    "class_label": 1.0,
    "bounding_box": 1.0
}
# initialize the optimizer, compile the model, and show the model
# summary
opt = Adam(lr=learning_rate)
model.compile(loss=losses, optimizer=opt, metrics=["accuracy"], loss_weights=lossWeights)
```

My call to "fit"

```
model.fit(x=train_generator[0], steps_per_epoch=train_generator[1],
          validation_data=validation_generator[0], validation_steps=validation_generator[1],
          epochs=epochs, verbose=1)
```

The weights that I load I've used in other experiments and downloaded them from [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/keras/vgg16) - (see vgg16_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5).

My Generator:

```
def generate_image_generator(generator, data_directory, df, subset, target_size, batch_size, shuffle, seed):
genImages = generator.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=df, directory=data_directory, target_size=target_size,
                                          x_col="file",
                                          y_col=['cls_onehot', 'bbox'],
                                          subset=subset,
                                          class_mode="multi_output",
                                          batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=shuffle, seed=seed)

while True:
    images, labels = genImages.next()

    targets = {
        'class_label': labels[0],
        'bounding_box': np.array(labels[1], dtype="float32")
    }
    yield images, targets   

def get_train_and_validate_generators(self, data_directory, files, max_images, validation_split, shuffle, seed, target_size):
        generator = ImageDataGenerator(validation_split=validation_split,
                                       rescale=1./255.)

        df = get_dataframe(data_directory, files)

        if max_images:
            df = df.head(max_images)

        train_generator = generate_image_generator(generator, data_directory, df, "training",
                                                   target_size,
                                                   self.batch_size,
                                                   shuffle, seed)

        valid_generator = generate_image_generator(generator, data_directory, df, "validation",
                                                   target_size,
                                                   self.batch_size,
                                                   shuffle, seed)
```

Loading the dataframe from a list of CSV

```
def get_dataframe(data_directory, files):
frames=[]
for di in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(data_directory+di["file"])
    frames.append(df)
df = pd.concat(frames)

df['cls_onehot'] = df['cls'].str.get_dummies().values.tolist()
df['bbox'] = df[['sxu', 'syu', 'exu', 'eyu']].values.tolist()
return df
```

A snippet of the CSV:

```
    id,file,sx,sy,ex,ey,cls,sxu,syu,exu,eyu,w,h
0,motorcycle.0001.jpg,31,19,233,141,motorcycle,0.1183206106870229,0.11801242236024845,0.8893129770992366,0.8757763975155279,262,161
1,motorcycle.0002.jpg,32,15,232,142,motorcycle,0.12167300380228137,0.09259259259259259,0.8821292775665399,0.8765432098765432,263,162
2,motorcycle.0003.jpg,30,20,234,143,motorcycle,0.11406844106463879,0.12269938650306748,0.8897338403041825,0.8773006134969326,263,163
3,motorcycle.0004.jpg,30,15,231,132,motorcycle,0.11450381679389313,0.1,0.8816793893129771,0.88,262,150
4,motorcycle.0005.jpg,31,19,232,145,motorcycle,0.1183206106870229,0.1144578313253012,0.8854961832061069,0.8734939759036144,262,166
```

When I load weights from "imagenet", rather than use those I received from kaggle, I see the very same increase in bounding box loss

```
    imodel = tf.keras.applications.vgg16.VGG16(weights="imagenet", include_top=False,
                                           input_tensor=Input(shape=(224, 224, 3)))
```

**The Question:**
Please provide suggestions on how to isolate this bounding box loss growth problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. It looks like the problem was not at all with my generator. The code was fine except for one silly oversight. I still had an old call to compile running. I called compile correctly the first time with the composite loss function. Then I called it a second time strictly with categorical cross entropy as the cost, effectively ignoring my bounding boxes.

Anyways, if someone stumbles on this post, I hope they find the complete view of how to do classification and object detection, with a generator function, useful.

I edited the above question with the correct details.. so it now reflects the right answer.

I'd still like to get the perspective of the experts who have had to dig into the workings of a model to better understand the underlying details that lead to loss calculation.

Now that I'm starting to understand tensorflow at the high-level, its clear how to recognize when things are working.. its not clear how to diagnose when things aren't working.